# How to access the translated DataCategoryName?

Tags: soql, translation

I'm using the following SOQL query to retrive the Data Category Name.

```
SELECT Id, ParentId, Parent.Title, DataCategoryGroupName, DataCategoryName 
FROM Knowledge__DataCategorySelection
WHERE Parent.PublishStatus = 'Online'
```

However, I have created some translations for this category name in Salesforce: 
**Setup > Translate > Setup component: Data Category.**

My question is, how can I access this translated version?
[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can try to use the `toLabel()` function available in SOQL. It will return the value of the field in the user's language if the translation in this language exists.

for example:

```
SELECT Id, ParentId, Parent.Title, DataCategoryGroupName, toLabel(DataCategoryName)
FROM Knowledge__DataCategorySelection
WHERE Parent.PublishStatus = 'Online'
```

https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.soql_sosl.meta/soql_sosl/sforce_api_calls_soql_select_tolabel.htm

Comment: Thanks, it worked